# How to find a co-working space in Vladivostok as a tourist?

Tags: work, vladivostok

I will spend a week in [Vladivostok](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Vladivostok), and will do some open source programming using my laptop for one or two days. I will need a place with:

- An electricity plug,
- A fast Internet connection,
- A chair.

My hotel does not provide that, so I am looking for a co-working space, but the only one listed at coworking.com requires prior registration, with a form that asks for a city and won't take Vladivostok nor Artyom for an answer ("Регион или город "Артём" не найден в системе").

Are there any co-working spaces that'd welcome a visiting tourist for a day? Or failing that, are there any places (libraries/etc) I could look at going to?

Comment: You could try a cybercafe or something similar? Here's a list: https://iprim.ru/en/catalog/internet-kafe--kompyuternie-klubi not sure how up-to-date it is. Another option would be to find service offices with a business lounge, but the usual suspects don't seem to be present in Vladivostok.

Comment: @jcaron: Good ideas, feel free to propose this as an answer :-)

Comment: If the forms for the coworking space you have found don't work, can you contact them directly instead and ask? From a quick search it looks like the one you're looking at is part of the university, so worst case you could contact the university even if you can find direct contact details for the space.

Comment: Nomadlist.com lists cafes in Vladivostok under the "Coworking" tab. https://nomadlist.com/vladivostok

Comment: @greenpenguin: It only lists one coworking space, the same as the one mentioned in the question.

Comment: Anticafes might also fit your bill, so you might as well check these.

Comment: @alamar: Very interesting, I did not know this concept! Please do post an answer if you can find any in Vladivostok, thanks! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-caf%C3%A9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some [anticafes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-caf%C3%A9) might be satisfying your check-list.

Yandex Maps list two of those [in Vladivostok](https://yandex.com/maps/-/CBFLi0B8LC) city center and two [in Artem](https://yandex.com/maps/-/CBFLiDQv8B).

Answer (score 3):

[Coworking.com](https://www.coworker.com/russia/vladivostok/ajax) lists AJAX, for example.

"AJAX" is a space for leisure and cultural activities on the campus of Far Eastern Federal University on the island "Russian".

It includes high speed wifi, free coffee and more.